# Generic ViewModel that works with ItemsControl

Tags: wpf

I implemented some generic `CustomControls` in WPF, for instance an `AutoCompleteTextBox`.
Now, I'd like to implement a generic `ViewModel` library, in order to perform the databind of these controls.

Now I defined one attached property named `CDataSource`, that specifies the source of the data to bind within the control.

My question is : Is it possible, that the `CustomControl` passes to the `ViewModel` the `CDataSource` value? In this way the `ViewModel` may populate the control on the basis of the `CDataSource` property.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The name CDataSource seems to be a little bit unusual. Try to use more meaningful names though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a strange request to me. You don't want any dependency on your view model from within your custom control. Instead, you would normally have a dependency property on your custom control which is the `ItemsSource`, and then you would set the value of this from your view in XAML.

This is how the `AutoCompleteBox` included in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) operates.

Comment: Not exactly. In my case the type of the property CDataSource is an enumeration. E.g.:
-CDataSource.BookData
-CDataSource.MusicData
-ecc...

Now, i'd like to have a ViewModel, that populates the ItemsControl of my autoComplete on the basis of the property CDataSource.
For instance, if I have the following control :
<myCustomCtrl CDataSource="CDataSource.BookData">
i'd like that the ViewModel, will automatically populates the control with the Book data.

Is this scenario possible?

Comment: What are the possible values for the enumeration? Whose responsibility is it to load the data based on the enumeration value?

Comment: Why wouldn't these both be set by the view? i.e. CDataSource="CDataSource.MusicData" ItemsSource={Binding MyMusicCollection}, where MyMusicCollection is an ObservableCollection on your view model, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply. I really appreciate your help.
The problem is that I have a lot of enumeration values (may be hundreds), so I'd like to avoid to have a property in my ViewModel for each enumeration value.

Comment: This is the reason why I was thinking to use a ViewModel Library, that for each ItemsControl with the CDataSource property, it automatically populates the control on the basis of the CDataSource.
I don't know if this method is applicable or not, and for this reason I'm completely opened to other solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure of the value of the enumeration. If it is to specify what gets populated in the control, then you're implying that it is the responsibility of the control to load the data. In which case, an ItemsSource property is not required. If you wish each view model to load the data, then it would seem to make sense to remove the enumeration completely, and just set an ItemsSource property to whatever collection you wish. This makes the text box much more generic.

Comment: If you're worried about replicated load code between view models, then you would implement a service to retrieve the data, most likely behind a repository pattern, and inject that service into each view model that requires it.